# Can't add user in SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, administration, groups

Currently I've been a group owner and have full control permission and I want to add a user to my group, but when I try to add it, I'm facing some issues that I don't have access and I cannot navigate to the site permissions even though the menu is there.

Is there any recommendation to solve this issue and speculation for the root cause?

I would be happy if I could discuss it.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you site collection admin for this site? Do you see "New" button inside the group or unable to access the group itself?

Comment: i'm using sharepoint 2019 on prem.
i'm not site collection admin of this site
I see the new button and can pick any user but when added, it said I don't have access

Comment: Are you able to open the group settings? There is an option like this: `Who can edit the membership of the group?` which indicates who can add users in the group. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yeah i'm able to open group settings, but not for site permission, option to "Who can edit the membership of the group" is only group owner. and I don't want to change it to group member

Comment: Do you know what permissions are granted to this group at site level permissions?

Comment: group permission is set to be read

Answer (score 0):

Check who can edit the group members, Set Who can edit the membership of the group to Group Owner:
[image]